# Electron installing abort - ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, npm, electron

I'm trying to install electron via npm and I get this error :
[image]
How can I solve it?

Comment: are you able to download other node_modules?

Comment: Yes I can download other modules

Answer (score 4):

You can set custom mirrors to download electron from a seperate mirror. Just add this before `npm install`, or inside the hooks somewhere.

```
ELECTRON_MIRROR="https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors/electron/"
```

I've always used this because github were extremely slow for electron release downloads even on the servers.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bad internet connection or a proxy issue.
You may want to try to remove your proxy:

```
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Comment: I try that, but same problem!

Answer (score 0):

It's better to install `electron` globally.
You can try
`npm i electron -g --verbose`
also update your npm before install electron
`npm i -g npm`

Comment: This will not help with the connection problem

Comment: I had always do that... install electron globally, and make app with that globally installed electron. after making app when i build for production i just copy the the electron module from global node_modules and paste into my project node_module :)